# A better approach to do MySql backup from an Electron.io app

Tags: mysql, node.js, electron, child-process

I want to understand how [node mysql module](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) works to understand how its operation has impact on execution performance on a [Electron.io Node](http://electron.atom.io/) app.

For example: I have to make some backup from a table with **2m (Million) lines** to another database. First i tried to do it with [node child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) on a Electron.io app. It works on development (`# electrion main.js` ), but it don`t work on a  [asar package](http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/application-packaging/) since it has it own child process restrictions.

Here is what I have to do:

#### Prepare the output database

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MY_SECOND_DATABASE.BACKUP_TABLE;
CREATE TABLE MY_SECOND_DATABASE.BACKUP_TABLE (
    `NumberField` int(11) NOT NULL
);
```

#### Backup from database source

`mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -proot MY_FIRST_DATABASE -e “SELECT NumberField FROM MY_TABLE” > /User/MacBook/Downloads/sql_output_content.txt`

#### Then copy to another database

`mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -proot MY_SECOND_DATABASE -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ‘/User/MacBook/Downloads/sql_output_content.txt’ INTO TABLE BACKUP_TABLE FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'"`

#### Doubts that have arisen

- Would be a better approach **if I use this node mysql plugin** to do the same operation since it does the same task I have doing on a spawn children process?
- Is there an alternative to accomplish more efficiently this task?

Answer (score 1):

In the Introduction section of the Readme of the module that you linked to, it's explained how to make a connection to the database:

- https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#introduction

You use two databases here (on the same host but two database names) so you would need to create two connections - for first database and second database.

The connection to second database would be used to drop the table and create a new one, then a connection to the first database would be used to get all the data, and the connection to the second database would be used to save all that data.

It's hard to say without testing which way would be faster for you but if you cannot spawn an external process then you have no option but to work with the database from Node.

Comment: Sometimes I will have to make complex operations that is better if I do it on child_process. This is the big wall I am in front!